# Android studio is creating tens of Java.exe processes

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, taskmanager

When I run android studio I noticed that it creates multiple java.exe processes, sometime when I don't pay attention the number goes up to 50+ until no more ram left.

this happened with three different projects.

[task manager showing 30+ java.exe process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgiMr.png)

I'm using latest version of android studio:

[android studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCzmQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this appears to happen only when my hotspot is enabled, after I disabled my hotspot this didn't happen.

Still this shouldn't be a solution as I can't use android studio when I share my internet? like.. WTF!